# SQLite Query Questions

Tags: sql, sqlite

2 questions:

First, in MSSQL, I can convert nvarchar to datetime by doing

```
cast('5/31/2011 12:00:00 AM' as datetime) as convertedtodate
```

Result: 2011-05-31 00:00:00.000

How do I do it in SQLite?

Second, what is the equivalent of MS SQL's `datediff` function on sqlite?  E.g.:

```
datediff(Day,'5/30/2011 12:00:00 AM','5/31/2011 12:00:00 AM') as DateAge
```

Result: 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your first question (convert string to date), the answer is "it depends".  Since SQLite does not have a specific date field, you may not need to convert it.  You could just store it in a string field (the options are sting, real, or int for date storage).  If you want to convert the string to an int (which would be the number of seconds since 1970-01-01), you would use the `strftime` method like so:

```
strftime('%s','2011-05-12 01:03:00')
```

As for the second part of your question (difference between two dates), you would use the following code in SQLite:

```
strftime('%s','2011-05-12 01:03:00') - strftime('%s','2011-05-08 11:54:09')
```

That will give you the number of seconds between the two dates.  You can play around with this information, as well as a lot more, to get exactly what you are looking for from SQLite.  Here are a couple resources that will help you out:

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @john ryan - what do you mean it doesn't work.  I tried it and it worked for me.  The first converted that date to the UNIX time format while the second gave me the number of seconds between two dates.  This information is being pulled right from the documentation, so I think it would be helpful to know what errors you are getting.

Comment: @john ryan - try `SELECT strftime('%s','2011-05 . . .;` and see if that works.