# Rails validate uniqueness of date ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have an application that involves absence records for employees.

I need to ensure that the start and end dates for each record don't overlap.

So for example, if I entered an absence record that started today and ended tomorrow, it shouldn't be possible to enter another inside of that date range in any way. So I couldn't make one that starts the day before today, then ends the day after tomorrow, or any later date.

To put it simply, I need to make the date range unique.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Custom validators in the model class that involve iterating through all records take far too long to complete, and I haven't found any gems that address this problem. I also haven't found any simply way to scope by uniqueness in the model either. I'm stumped :/

Thanks for your time!

Edit:

```
class Absence < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :date, :date_ended, :status, :reason, :form, :user_id, :tempuser, :company_id
belongs_to :user
default_scope { where(company_id: Company.current_id) }

validates :date, :date_ended, :status, :reason, :form, :user_id, presence: true 
validates_numericality_of :user_id, :only_integer => true, :message => "can only be whole number."
end
```

Comment: Possibly by creating a model to record used dates? Something like EmployeeAbsenceDate. This would be quicker than iterating over all records.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I use these:

```
  scope :overlaps, ->(start_date, end_date) do
    where "(DATEDIFF(start_date, ?) * DATEDIFF(?, end_date)) >= 0", end_date, start_date
  end

  def overlaps?
    overlaps.exists?
  end

  # Others are models to be compared with your current model
  # you can get these with a where for example
  def overlaps
    siblings.overlaps start_date, end_date
  end

  validate :not_overlap

  def not_overlap
    errors.add(:key, 'message') if overlaps?
  end

  # -1 is when you have a nil id, so you will get all persisted user absences
  # I think -1 could be omitted, but did not work for me, as far as I remember
  def siblings
    user.absences.where('id != ?', id || -1)
  end
```

Source: https://makandracards.com/makandra/984-test-if-two-date-ranges-overlap-in-ruby-or-rails

Comment: Could you explain what those siblings were that you used in the previous example? And how does one go about actually using your overlaps scope? Just by validating the uniqueness of the two dates by the overlaps scope?

Comment: do you want not more than one absences in an given period for a given user? going to update assuming this.

Comment: Yes, each user should only be allowed an absence record from 1/1/2013 to, for example, 10/1/2013. All dates in between those dates are off-limits for any other absence records, for that user.

Comment: I'm getting an "undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass" error and "You need to supply at least one validation" on "validates :not_overlap". What exactly is a sibling by the way? I might be able to contribute more if I knew. I'm far from an expert on scoping, ha! Edit: Ah, I see that you're defining it in the new code. Cheers!

Comment: replace :key with :base, siblings are siblings of one absence, meaning absences from same user except the current absence

Comment: It's still complaining about needing at least one validation on "validates :not_overlap". The undefined method was because it didn't know what "user" was, but I fixed that one.

Comment: Could the default scope be somehow causing this problem? It shouldn't, since all of my records have correct scoping data

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, and I think it should be validate, not validates on the :not_overlap?

Comment: Now it's an SQLite problem... It doesn't know what Datediff is. Would http://lists.edgewall.com/archive/trac/2005-May/003124.html work instead?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972163/sqlite-query-questions

Comment: No worries man, I got it working by replacing the SQL in the overlaps scope with this:
    where "( (julianday(Date(date)) - julianday(?)))* ((julianday(Date(?)) - julianday(date_ended))  ) >= 0", date_ended, date                                                                                    Thanks for all the help by the way, not many people would spend three hours helping out a complete stranger. If I can repay the favour, let me know! Good luck!

Comment: ``user.absences.where.not(id: id)`` will generate correct statement, no need for -1. Requires Rails 4 though.

Answer (score 9):

Use the gem [`validates_overlap`](https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap).

```
gem 'validates_overlap'
```

For example, if you have a model called `Meeting` with a `start_date` and `end_date` fields of type `date`, you can easily validate that they don't overlap.

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :start_date, :end_date, overlap: true 
end
```

---

Another more realistic example, say a `Meeting` belongs_to a `User`, you can scope it out, so it only validates meetings for a particular user.

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to User
  validates :start_date, :end_date, overlap: { scope: 'user_id',
                                             message_content: 'overlaps with Users other meetings.' }
end
```

Answer (score 8):

As a modification to the accepted answer, here's an overlaps scope that will work for DBs that don't understand  DATEDIFF

```
  scope :overlaps, ->(start_date, end_date) do
    where "((start_date <= ?) and (end_date >= ?))", end_date, start_date
  end
```

This draws on the solution for [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: honestly, using `>=` and `<=` seems more readable and portable than `DATEDIFF` even if your DB does support `DATEDIFF`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a gem called [validates_overlap](https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap) which allows you to easily validate date range overlaps. You can also use scopes on the validation.

Answer (score 1):

While juanpastas solution is correct, it will be valid for creation of records, but can lead to false negative validations on updates.

If you need to edit an existing record, say the range is 2014-03-13..2014-06-12 and you want to reduce it to 2014-03-13..2014-04-12, you'll get an overlap error because it is checking AGAINST itself.

```
  def siblings
    Absence_users.where('user_id = ? AND id != ?', user_id, self)
  end
```

will obviate that shortcoming.
(Dave T's addition should also be followed, being DB-agnostic.)