# Validate date range exist in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array of object. Every object have a `start_date` and and `end_date (DATETIME).`

I save it with : `@arroy_of_objects.each(&:save)`

But I can't have two date in the same time. If a start_date is equal and between an another date range, I don't want to save it.

How can I do it with rails ? In a validate in the model or directly in my controller

Comment: I think [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252423/rails-validate-uniqueness-of-date-ranges) is similar to you, and desired answer as well.

Comment: What database do you use?